# Excerpt textarea missing on post editing page in admin panel

Tags: wp-admin, excerpt

Why is that? It's a new installation.

EDIT: I don't have plugins installed and I tried to restore default theme to Twenty Ten, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upper right corner in posts editing page > "Screen Options"...there you have to check "Excerpt" ;)

Comment: arrgh... that was a stupid question. :)

Comment: I've been more than 30 minutes searching the solution at why I couldn't edit the posts' excerpts in WP Admin, so I don't think that the question is stupid. I didn't know that the WP display options feauture existed, they didn't taught it to me at school. Thanks for the solution, you rock. I like WP much, it's pitty that this feature is not user friendly.

Comment: If you need it on Pages, then see http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/add-excerpts-to-your-pages-in-wordpress/

Comment: i almost reinstalled Wordpress !! phew

Answer (score 0):

If you already tried to add it at Screen Options in Upper Right Corner (in older versions)... try it:

Add the following code to your theme’s **functions.php** file or a site-specific plugin:

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```